# Using 'for' as a prop in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use a React library (Dev Extreme React Grid) for a project I'm working on, and encountering an issue I'm struggling to find much information on. To make a long story short, I'm trying to use a provided component that requires a prop, with the name "for". Like so:

```
<DataTypeProvider
    for={someData}
 />
```

Now, I'm running into an issue since `for` is a reserved word in js, and is (reasonably) converted to `htmlFor`. However, this causes `DataTypeProvider` to lack the expected prop `for`. To confirm this suspicion, I dug into the source and mapped `htmlFor` to be a backup in case `for` wasn't provided, and the code worked as expected. Obviously this isn't an ideal solution, does anyone know of a way around this reserved word issue? I'm not able to understand how this could ever work in react, and "for" is not a great search term for googling ha.

Thanks for an ideas, suggestions, or solutions!

Comment: But why did you call it `for` when the content is `someData`? Reasonably speaking, you want to call that attribute `data` and then bootstrap that using a var that's also called `data` so you can do things like `const { data, blah } = this.props; <DataTypeProvide data={data} blah={blah}/>`, with that component making sure to use the correct markup for getting the extended `for` rendered into the real HTML (rather than into a JSX component)

Comment: Hey Mike. I am using DataTypeProvider from a library I'm importing, I didn't make it, nor do I have the ability to change its name. The prop being named 'for' is outside of my control, and I agree that it makes its use way more complicated than needed. Hope that gives some clarity to the issue.

Comment: It does, and as additional details around that component: please update your post to make it clear that you didn't write DataTypeProvider. Plenty of folks won't be familiar with Dev Extreme React Grid, and so have no idea what its components are called. Ideally, add a little link to their DataTypeProvider API docs, too - small thing, but makes a post quite a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `jsx` notation spread an `object` which contains a key named `for`

```
const props = {
    for : '/foo'
} 

return <Child {...props} />
```

Notice that you can't access it using `destructuring assignment`

```
const Child = ({for}) => <div>{for}</div> //ERROR
const Child = props => <div>{props.for}</div> //Nice
```

obs: What a terrible API decision to expect a `prop` named as a `keyword`, `to` sounds just as good and wont cause any problems

[image: Edit confident-dawn-hzi2g]

Comment: Gave this a go, and seemed to work pretty well. 

Thanks for you help + confirmation that this API isn't well-named ha!

Comment: Glad to hear! Passing a prop named `For` and rename it inside the component can work as well, as long as you can edit the source for the library of course